# Git: Which repository structure reduces the risk of merge conflicts?

Tags: git, database-design, merge

I am going to setup a git repo to sync some data across multiple clients. As the git repo is not accessible - and not even known - to the user, I want to setup a file structure which (if possible) eliminates the risk of merge conflicts when pushing to other clients.
So simplify the complex data structures which I am going to store, let's use the metaphor 'Articles with comments' to talk about the data.

I was thinking of three alternatives:

```
/repository.git/Article1/Article.xml
                     .../Comment1.xml
                     .../Comment2.xml
```

or

```
/repository.git/Article1/Article_with_comments_appended.xml
```

or

```
/repository.git/All_Articles_including_their_comments.xml
```

My users are able to:

- Edit whole articles (seldom)
- Add comments (often)
- Delete comments (seldom)

All other actions - especially deleting articles - will not be used.

So which alternative reduces the risk of merge conflicts most? Are there other ones? What about the tradeoff performance (alternative 3) vs. decreased risk of merge conflicts (alternative 1 & 2)?

Comment: What about not using incremented numbers but UUIDs for identification of the comments? That way you eliminate the risk of a conflict if two users comment the same article at the same time.

Comment: good point. I'll use hashes instead of numbers.